# Android device react-native fetch network request failed

Tags: react-native, fetch

The following lines of code, works on an iPhone (device not emulator) but not on an Android device.

```
try {
  const response = yield fetch("https://myapi.coolapp.com/v1/tokens/", {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    email: action.email,
    password: action.password,
    tokenDuration: 100000000,
    app: true,
  }),
});
```

Read most similar questions here at stackoverflow but to no avail. Any tips?